# How to read a file in Python 3.6 and separate it's content

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read a file on Python 3.6 and store his information on two different variables, the first one storing the "exemplars" from the #list of exemplars and the other one storing the "samples" from the #list of samples. However I only get one line from the first list and the entire second list.

The file that I am reading: 
[image]

This is what I get:

> ## First list
>
> ff44578jhT marsBug 2 7 3 5 2 1 71 235 312
>
> ## Second list
>
> k345fv78 littleMonster 2 4 3 0 2 1 89 2345 0
>
> k434fv78 bigMonster 1 3 3 0 2 1 89 2345 0
>
> k623fv78 hugeMonster 2 4 3 0 2 1 89 2345 0
>
> k13ued31 edu 3 2 1 8 0 1 20 4 0
>
> k123vv31 notbigMonster 4 8 9 3 4 2 200 4000 0

And this is what I should get:

> ## First list
>
> ff44578jhT marsBug 2 7 3 5 2 1 71 235 312
>
> ff11443asT; momu; 4; 2; 1; 4; 6; 3; 1; 11; 23
>
> ff1123dasT; nomu; 1; 3; 1; 2; 3; 2; 1; 1; 3
>
> ff44578jhT; jupiterBug; 2; 7; 3; 5; 2; 1; 71; 235; 312
>
> ff44578jhT; uranusBug; 2; 7; 3; 5; 2; 1; 71; 235; 312
>
> k123vv31; bibug; 4; 8; 9; 3; 4; 2; 200; 4000; 0
>
> ## Second list
>
> k345fv78 littleMonster 2 4 3 0 2 1 89 2345 0
>
> k434fv78 bigMonster 1 3 3 0 2 1 89 2345 0
>
> k623fv78 hugeMonster 2 4 3 0 2 1 89 2345 0
>
> k13ued31 edu 3 2 1 8 0 1 20 4 0
>
> k123vv31 notbigMonster 4 8 9 3 4 2 200 4000 0

```
def readFromFile(file_name):
    examplars=[]
    samples=[]
    in_file = open(file_name, 'r')

    if "#List of exemplars:\n" in in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, info6, info7, info8, info9, info10, info11 = line.split("; ")
            print(info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, info6, info7, info8, info9, info10, info11) #using print to see what is happening but the objective would be to append all the infos in a tuple
            if "#List of samples:\n" in in_file:
                    for line in in_file:
                        info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, info6, info7, info8, info9, info10, info11 = line.split("; ")
                        print(info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, info6, info7, info8, info9, info10, info11) #using print to see what is happening but the objective would be to append all the infos in a tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Preston Hager mentioned, the format of your file suggests that you should use the `csv` module. However, another approach without using `csv` and reading from a `.txt` file would be this:

```
with open("examples.txt", "r") as inFile:

    #Read all data from file.
    data = inFile.read()

    #Split each set to examples and samples.
    examples = data.split("#")[1].split(":\n")[1].split("\n")
    samples = data.split("#")[2].split(":\n")[1].split("\n")

    #Create sublists of every example or sample record and dispose the last record which is empty.
    examples = [example.split(";") for example in examples][:-1]
    samples = [sample.split(";") for sample in samples][:-1]

    #Print results.
    print("Examples: ")
    for example in examples:
        print(example)

    print("Samples: ")
    for sample in samples:
        print(sample)
```

Output:

```
 Examples: 
['ff44578jhT', ' marsBug', ' 2', ' 7', ' 3', ' 5', ' 2', ' 1', ' 71', ' 235', ' 312']
['ff11443asT', ' momu', ' 4', ' 2', ' 1', ' 4', ' 6', ' 3', ' 1', ' 11', ' 23']
['ff1123dasT', ' nomu', ' 1', ' 3', ' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 2', ' 1', ' 1', ' 3']
['ff44578jhT', ' jupiterBug', ' 2', ' 7', ' 3', ' 5', ' 2', ' 1', ' 71', ' 235', ' 312']
['ff44578jhT', ' uranusBug', ' 2', ' 7', ' 3', ' 5', ' 2', ' 1', ' 71', ' 235', ' 312']
['k123vv31', ' bibug', ' 4', ' 8', ' 9', ' 3', ' 4', ' 2', ' 200', ' 4000', ' 0']
Samples: 
['k345fv78', ' littleMonster', ' 2', ' 4', ' 3', ' 0', ' 2', ' 1', ' 89', ' 2345', ' 0']
['k434fv78', ' bigMonster', ' 1', ' 3', ' 3', ' 0', ' 2', ' 1', ' 89', ' 2345', ' 0']
['k623fv78', ' hugeMonster', ' 2', ' 4', ' 3', ' 0', ' 2', ' 1', ' 89', ' 2345', ' 0']
['k13ued31', ' edu', ' 3', ' 2', ' 1', ' 8', ' 0', ' 1', ' 20', ' 4', ' 0']
```

Comment: That's exacly what I was looking for! An aproach without using other modules! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) with ';' separator:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt', separator = ';', header=None)
```

Just read in both files and then manipulate the dataframes to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way you've formatted and what you're trying to get I would suggest the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Don't worry if you have large lists in this format with colons though, Python's csv module will let you change the separator too.

Here's some code you might be able to use:

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='; ')
```

Then to get the contents of each one the reader object basicaly functions as a list.

```
print(reader[row][column])
```

That will print the value at the row and column. You may have to create headers for your files for it to work in Python. Check the Python Docs for more information.